# Multiple Zend applications on same host

Tags: apache-config

I'm developing a Zend application that should be installed on a host that I don't access to it. I have two problems:

1. On the server there is no zend-server-ce installation.
2. Application should be installed beside some other CMS'es like wordpress and Jumla.

There is two choices available for me to implement, first one is place each cms in a sub-domain and second is place each cms in a folder.

for example first one may look like this:

```
blog.host.com --> for Wordpress
contents.host.com --> for Jumla 
management.host.com --> for zend application
```

and second one may be:

```
host.com/blog --> for Wordpress
host.com/contents --> for Jumla 
host.com/management --> for zend application
```

I can't configure Document Root for some specific folder on host. Currently I configured a virtual host on my local machine changing `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` to:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/my_project/name/public"
        ServerName pl.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

So what should I do for doing same on a host that I don't access to it's apache?

Comment: how you will edit apache config _on a host that I don't access to it_

Comment: I mean I want to know what should I do instead...

Answer (score -1):

as for me - better way is to use sub-domains.

config fo example blog.host.com
DocumentRoot - is a full path to index.php

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/blog.host.com/www"
        ServerName blog.host.com
</VirtualHost>
```

for zend application - just read *docs/README.txt* in your project witch looks like:

```
README
======

This directory should be used to place project specfic documentation including
but not limited to project notes, generated API/phpdoc documentation, or
manual files generated or hand written.  Ideally, this directory would remain
in your development environment only and should not be deployed with your
application to it's final production location.


Setting Up Your VHOST
=====================

The following is a sample VHOST you might want to consider for your project.

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/mnt/winc/www/zend_test/public"
   ServerName zend_test.local

   # This should be omitted in the production environment
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

   <Directory "/mnt/winc/www/zend_test/public">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

but when deploying `Indexes` better set to `-Indexes` to disallow browsing your files.

**EDIT 1**

also check apache doc for [options](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options)
and [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

for detailed information

Comment: I don't have access to web server's apache! also you didn't say what should I do for zend libraries?

Comment: @Sorush Rabiee then what for the question if you don't have access to server - then you can't put the anything at all. about zend libraries... just put them into /library folder in your project (each project or top level folder even not reachable via http '/home/subdigger/libs/Zend/Library') & use it like include or  set_include_path.

Comment: I can put files on server but cant edit `/etc/apache/httpd` for virtual hosts and enable overriding.

Comment: @Sorush Rabiee this mean the only way for you is `host.com/blog`